# Force greaterThan with numbers in Zend Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm using the following code:

```
$age=10; //user input
$select
    ->columns(["id"=>"id"])
    ->where->greaterThan("age",$age);

echo $select->getSqlString();
```

This gives me the folowing result:

```
SELECT "program"."id" AS "id" FROM "program" WHERE "age" > '10'
```

However, I would like to use the `>` for ints, eg have the resulting query

```
SELECT "program"."id" AS "id" FROM "program" WHERE "age" > 10
```

How can I achieve that using the `greaterThan` predicate?

I know I can also write `->where("age > $age");` but that's not secure nor beautiful.

Comment: You can use `->where('age > ?', $age)` thus removing the security issue.

Comment: Somehow when I write `->where('age > ?', $age)` , The variable is not put into the query. Eg results in `SELECT "program"."id" AS "id" FROM "program" WHERE age > `

Comment: Ah, I thought you were using ZF 1.x. No idea for ZF 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no difference between the two SQL Statements:

```
SELECT "program"."id" AS "id" FROM "program" WHERE "age" > '10'
SELECT "program"."id" AS "id" FROM "program" WHERE "age" > 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#equalto-lessthan-greaterthan-lessthanorequalto-greaterthanorequalto), `greaterThan` has this function header:

```
public function greaterThan($left, $right, $leftType = self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER, $rightType = self::TYPE_VALUE);
```

Though not documented, setting `$rightType` to the type of `Predicate::TYPE_LITERAL` might expose the literal integer value. I do not know whether `TYPE_LITERAL` values are still being escaped properly. Please verify.

Comment: This gives  `"Invalid type "literal" provided; must be of type "Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator::TYPE_IDENTIFIER" or "Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Operator::TYPE_VALUE""` Seems that TYPE_LITERAL is not more supported. I'm running 2.2

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be much difference between the two. You can still do this by:

```
$age=10; //user input
$select
    ->columns(["id"=>"id"])
    ->where->greaterThan("age",(int) $age); // type cast to int and datatype of age coloumn in database should also be taken integer

echo $select->getSqlString();
```

Comment: It's Zend that is converting the $age which is already an int to '$int'. Doing what you suggest doesn't change the problem.